# How can i get User name in a table where user_id is used as foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs

I am using Devise gem for user Authentication. User id is as foreign key in article table 
How can i get writer name through User_id in a view Show_article.html.erb
I can access user_id in show_article.htmlerb

I have tried to make a custom function in article controller but could not get the desired output

Comment: in your `articles/show.html.erb` page you can access user name by `@atricle.user.name` OR `@atricle.user.first_name` which ever works. Did you define relations in models for `has_many` and `belongs_to` ?

Comment: Yes i have already defined relations
and i am getting an error of undefined method on accessing @atricle.user.name

Comment: what is the exact error? Please share error and view `show.html.erb`, model `article.rb` and `user.rb`

Comment: On writing @article.user.name
Error: No method error in Articles#show
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: and are you sure you have user_id stored in @article? try replacing `@article.user.name` with `@article.user_id` and see does that show something? if yes then there is something wrong with your relations. Or may be you created `@article` before implementing `User` logic.

Comment: here is a link to these files href="https://1drv.ms/f/s!AmS-GpiY4Gs8jwlHqGw92tmqKJh-

Comment: yes! @article.user_id shows user_id 
I followed a tutorial to link article and user(devise gem authenticated)

Comment: @Bhupati he is talking about show page which have only 1 article so there is no ''all of those articles"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Article model should look like this:

```
class Article << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  #....some more lines
end
```

your User model should look like this:

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
  #....some more lines
end
```

and your `show.html.erb` should say:

```
  #....your rest of code
<%= @article.try(:user).try(:name) %>
  #....your rest of code
```

This will skip user name if you article doesn't have any user. It looks like your article doesn't have user_id or you haven't defined your relations correctly.

Comment: ** Thanks alot **
Sorry! relations were not defined correctly

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that some of your article do not have any user. so
you can do

`<%= @article&.user&.name %>` in show page

and in the index page

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= article&.user&.name%></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Delete', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this article?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

but make sure you have ruby 2.3.0 or higher